# How can the player lose an life when it clicks on an object? GameMaker Studio

Tags: game-maker, gml

I'm trying to figure out how player can lose an life when clicking on an object. This is what I have so far:

Object_Controller

Create Event:

```
lives=3
```

Step Event:

```
if mouse_check_button_pressed(object_wrong_answer)
   {
   lives -= 1;
if lives < 1 room_restart() 
}
```

However this isn't working. Any advice or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use object's name in `mouse_check_button_pressed()`, it needs [mouse button constant](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/mouse,%20keyboard%20and%20other%20controls/mouse%20input/index.html).

For solve your problem you should add `Mouse`->`Left Pressed` Event into `object_wrong_answer` object and place your code (`lives -= 1; if lives < 1 room_restart()`) there.